# Error converting a LINQ query with a TimeSpan? to a List<>?

Tags: c#, list, linq-to-sql, nullable, timespan

I run the following LINQ to SQL query

```
var q =
    from O in db.GetTable<OptionsTraded>()
    where O.TradeDate.Date == dtpVolReport.Value.Date
    select new { O.TradeTime };
```

but when I try and convert this output to a list:

```
var qq = q.ToList();
```

I get the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in System.Data.dll Additional information: Specified cast is not
>   valid.

I only get this error when selecting the `O.TradeTime` attribute and this is mapped to a property with type `TimeSpan?` and I am sure that this is the route of the problem. If I try select any other attribute in my table, include those mapped to other nullable types such as `int?` or `double?` I do not get an error.

Has anyone encountered this before or can recommend what the correct way to deal with a `TimeSpan?` is?

This is how `OptionsTraded` is defined:

```
[Table(Name = "OptionsTraded")]
    public class OptionsTraded
    {
        private DateTime _TradeDate;
        [Column(Storage = "_TradeDate")]
        public DateTime TradeDate
        {
            get { return this._TradeDate; }
            set { this._TradeDate = value; }
        }

        private TimeSpan? _TradeTime;
        [Column(Storage = "_TradeTime")]
        public TimeSpan? TradeTime
        {
            get { return this._TradeTime; }
            set { this._TradeTime = value; }
        }
        .
        .
        .
```

And in SQL-Server:

[image]

I have also tried:

```
public class TradeViewModel
{
    public TimeSpan? TradeTime { get; set; }
}

var q =
    from O in db.GetTable<OptionsTraded>()
    where O.TradeDate.Date == dtpVolReport.Value.Date
    select new TradeViewModel {TradeTime = O.TradeTime};

var qq = q.ToList();
```

but I get the same error still

Comment: Hi, can you show us the part with the `TimeSpan` deceleration and mapping? Besides that, I would recomment a null check for: `dtpVolReport.Value.Date`, like: `dtpVolReport.HasValue && O.TradeDate.Date == dtpVolReport.Value.Date`

Comment: And what is the underlying type in SQL for that "TradeDate" ? Also, keep in mind that this is nullable so in case O.TradeDate is null then you will break your query by accessing TradeDate.Date. Check first TradeDate.HasValue && TradeDate.Date == dtpVolReport.Value.Date

Comment: @VidasVasiliauskas added those details to the question.

Comment: @Stefan `dtpVolReport` is a `DateTimePicker` so it's never going to be null. I've added the declaration with the `TimeSpan`. Is this the wrong way to use LINQ maybe? I'm more used to just typing out SQL queries as strings in my code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this article ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sbajaj/archive/2008/05/14/what-s-new-in-linq-to-sql-sp1.aspx ) you should decorate the TimeSpan with this attribute

```
[Column(CanBeNull = true, DbType = "TIME(7) NULL")]
public TimeSpan? TradeTime 
{
     //...
```

Be advised that your SQL definition contains `time(0)` instead of `TIME(7)`. It's worth to check if this doesn't lead to any complications.

For other readers: you'll also need:

- .NET 3.5 SP1 or later
- MS SQL 2008 Eninge (express or regular)

In addition, here's a list with the operations that are supported and translated to SQL:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882662%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Beware of the addition and substraction:

> Although the CLR System.TimeSpan type does support addition and subtraction, the SQL TIME type does not. Because of this, your LINQ to SQL queries will generate errors if they attempt addition and subtraction when they are mapped to the SQL TIME type. You can find other considerations for working with SQL date and time types in SQL-CLR Type Mapping (LINQ to SQL).